# How to set multiple attributes with one value function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, attributes

Given a datum containing multiple data elements, such as an object or array, is it possible to set multiple attributes on a selection with a single value function?

E.g. something like:

```
var data = [{ 'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'r': 5 }];
d3.select('body').append('svg').selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx cy r', function (d) {
        return [d.x, d.y, d.r];
    });
```

instead of:

```
var data = [{ 'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'r': 5 }];
d3.select('body').append('svg').selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return d.x;
    });
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });
    .attr('r', function (d) {
        return d.r;
    });
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**UPDATE** (July 8th 2016) This answer applies to d3 v3.x — NOT v4.x. For the latter version, see [Tim Hayes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38209449/1113023), also on this page. Or... just swap `attr` with `attrs` in my answer below, and don't forget to require/import/script-embed `d3-selection-multi`. And... don't miss the bit about using `.each`, which may be useful to you.

---

Yeah, it's possible by passing in a hash (like jQuery's `css()` method):

```
d3.select('body').append('svg').selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
.enter().append('circle')
  .attr({
    cx: function (d) { return d.x; },
    cy: function (d) { return d.y; },
    r:  function (d) { return d.r; }
  });
```

This works for `style()` as well.

If the reoccurring `function (d) {}` start to feel like too much, this is another approach:

```
d3.select('body').append('svg').selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .each(function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr({
      cx: d.x,
      cy: d.y,
      r:  d.r
    });
  })
```

NOTE: this feature only exists in d3.js v2.10.0 or higher

Comment: I asked for two reasons: one, to be able to write more succinct code, and two, to minimize function calls. The first syntax you provide is handy, but the second is closer to what i'm looking for -- one function call for each node.

Is there any way to avoid wrapping `this` in a d3 selector and still set attributes? (I suppose I could just use native JS, but that's veering dangerously close to sacrificing legibility for performance.)

Comment: No way to skip the wrapping of `this` afaik. I too used to be occupied with optimization, but nowadays I try to to relax about, bc it's often not an issue. Still... you can use native JS, as you point out, and perhaps abstract things for legibility. Like `.each(function (d) { applyAttr(this, { cx: d.x, cy: dy, r: d.r }); })` where the implementation of `applyAttr` can use native JS if you wish. Or, if there's a 1-to-1 relationship between data and dom elements, you can cache the wrapped `d3.select(this)` as a property of of `d`, to avoid re-wrapping in subsequent refreshes.

Comment: BTW, the abstraction from the last comment could also be done to look like this: `.each( applyAttr(function (d) { return { cx: d.x, cy: dy, r: d.r }; })`

Comment: @ericsoco re: reducing function calls. The `d3-selection-multi`docs for `.attrs` describes it as `"A convenience method on top of selection.attr for setting multiple attributes."` Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/blob/master/src/selection/attrs.js) confirms that it just calls `.attr` in a loop.

Answer (score 73):

This is an old post, but I found it while Googling around for an answer. The accepted answer no longer works in D3 v4.0.

Moving forward, you can do the same by using the `attrs()` method. But `attrs()` is only supported if you load the optional [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) script.

So using the example above, it would look like this in D3 v4.0:

```
// load d3-selection-multi as separate script
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>

d3.select('body').append('svg').selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attrs({
    cx: function (d) { return d.x; },
    cy: function (d) { return d.y; },
    r:  function (d) { return d.r; }
  });
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could version accepted answers, right? Thanks for adding this.

Comment: See the last paragraph of the [4.0 release notes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection): `...the multi-value methods—where you pass an object to set multiple attributes, styles or properties simultaneously—have been extracted to d3-selection-multi and are no longer part of the default bundle. The multi-value map methods have also been renamed to plural form to reduce overload...` The `d3-selection-multi` notes state: `the single-value methods such as selection.attr are recommended for most users, as there is little benefit to the shorter syntax...`

Comment: Nice reference @brichins - "... there is little benefit..." is so subjective. One huge benefit is being able to treat attributes as an object and pass it to multiple `attr` calls in D3 version 3 - strange that they took such a strong stance on this.

Comment: For those looking to pass styling to multiple `attr()` calls, you can also do, eg,  `svg.append("style").text("text {font-family: sans-serif;}");`

Answer (score 0):

Since [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) is now archived and doesn't work with the latest version of d3, the following will provide you with the same functionality:

```js
d3.selection.prototype.styles = function(map) {
  for (const name in map) this.style(name, map[name])
  return this
}
```

This is adapted from https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/blob/master/src/selection/styles.js