# Call function to set D3 SVG rect attributes just once for each datum

Tags: d3.js

I have this D3 code snippet that draws a table from data.

```
self.displayStateTable = function (stateTable) {
    d3.select('#VisualizationSVG')
    .selectAll('rect').data(stateTable).enter().append('rect')
    .attr({
        x: function (d, i) { return self.positionStateTableTile(d).x; },
        y: function (d, i) { return self.positionStateTableTile(d).y; },
        width: self.stateTableConfig.TileWidth,
        height: self.stateTableConfig.TileHeight,
        fill: function (d, i) { return self.positionStateTableTile(d).fill; }
    });
};
```

The function `positionStateTableTile` which works out the x position, the y position, and the fill for each datum's tile is run three times for each datum when it only needs to be run once. How can I change this so that D3 only calls `positionStateTableTile` once for each datum instead of three times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical - no sooner had  posted the question than the answer seemed obvious!

I can run the function once for each datum first and store the results in an array and use that to set the attributes in D3.

```
self.displayStateTable = function (stateTable) {
    var i = 0, stateTableTilePositions = [];
    for (i = 0; i < stateTable.length; i++) {
        stateTableTilePositions[i] = self.positionStateTableTile(stateTable[i]);
    }
    d3.select('#VisualizationSVG')
    .selectAll('rect').data(stateTable).enter().append('rect')
    .attr({
        x: function (d, i) { return stateTableTilePositions[i].x; },
        y: function (d, i) { return stateTableTilePositions[i].y; },
        width: self.stateTableConfig.TileWidth,
        height: self.stateTableConfig.TileHeight,
        fill: function (d, i) { return stateTableTilePositions[i].fill; }
    });
};
```

Comment: Please check this post for an alternative, which I think does this in a single step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822466/how-to-set-multiple-attributes-with-one-value-function