# d3 set multiple attributes with one function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, attributes

Hello everyone I have the following example object for a svg line

```
{
  _id: 5,
  coordinates:{
       x1: 100,
       y1: 100,
       x2: 500,
       y2: 500,
 }
```

Suppose I have an array of these objects within a variable `data`.
I want to set all relevant line attributes within one `attr()` call.
I know you can pass an object as an attribute, then d3 will set all attributes.
Since I'm having an array of object, I created a function returning the object:

```
let objectsRender = svg.selectAll("line")
                       .data(data)
                       .enter()
                       .append("line")
                       .attr(function(d)      { return d.coordinates;})
                       .attr("id", function(d){ return prefix +d._id;});
```

but it does not seem to work, as no x or y values are set.
Can anyone give me a solution to my problem?

Comment: It's the attributes x1,y1,x2,y2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set multiple attributes with one value function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822466/how-to-set-multiple-attributes-with-one-value-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that in one line, you have to do :

```
.attr({
    x1: function (d) { return d.coordinates.x1; },
    x2: function (d) { return d.coordinates.x2; },
    y1:  function (d) { return d.coordinates.y1; },
    y2:  function (d) { return d.coordinates.y2; }
  });
```