# Migrating from D3.js v3 to D3.js v4 not working - a select issue?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to migrate this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/4Qm6A/7/) which is in D3 v3 to D3 v4, but it is not working.

I know D3 drag behavior is now simply `d3.drag()` which I've changed, but when trying to run it, it is giving an error on line 53:

```
rect = d3.select(self.rectangleElement[0][0]);
```

with Chrome saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

How do I go about changing this JSFiddle so it runs in D3 v4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why are you re-selecting those things? They are already the selection you want. For example, self.rectangleElement is the selection of the rect. Second, passing an object to .attr is [no longer supported in version 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38209449/16363).  Third, the drag behavior has changed and the circle are eating your second mouse down.  Here's a version where I've fixed up these things:

```js
d3.select('#rectangle').on('click', function(){ new Rectangle(); });

var w = 600, h = 500;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

function Rectangle() {
    var self = this, rect, rectData = [], isDown = false, m1, m2, isDrag = false;
    
    svg.on('mousedown', function() {
      console.log(isDown);
        m1 = d3.mouse(this);
        if (!isDown && !isDrag) {
            self.rectData = [ { x: m1[0], y: m1[1] }, { x: m1[0], y: m1[1] } ];
            self.rectangleElement = d3.select('svg').append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle').call(dragR);
            self.pointElement1 = d3.select('svg').append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC1);
            self.pointElement2 = d3.select('svg').append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC2);            
            self.pointElement3 = svg.append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC3);
            self.pointElement4 = svg.append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC4);
            updateRect();
            isDrag = false;
        } else { 
            isDrag = true;
        }
        isDown = !isDown;   
    })
    
    .on('mousemove', function() {
        m2 = d3.mouse(this);
        if(isDown && !isDrag) { 
            self.rectData[1] = { x: m2[0] - 5, y: m2[1] - 5};
            updateRect();
        } 
    });  
    
    function updateRect() {  
        self.rectangleElement
          .attr("x", self.rectData[1].x - self.rectData[0].x > 0 ? self.rectData[0].x : self.rectData[1].x)
            .attr("y", self.rectData[1].y - self.rectData[0].y > 0 ? self.rectData[0].y :  self.rectData[1].y)
            .attr("width", Math.abs(self.rectData[1].x - self.rectData[0].x))
            .attr("height", Math.abs(self.rectData[1].y - self.rectData[0].y));  

        var point1 = self.pointElement1.data(self.rectData);
        point1.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[0].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[0].y);        
        var point2 = self.pointElement2.data(self.rectData);
        point2.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y);
        var point3 = self.pointElement3.data(self.rectData);
        point3.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[0].y);        
        var point3 = self.pointElement4.data(self.rectData);
        point3.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[0].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y);
    }
    
    var dragR = d3.drag().on('drag', dragRect);
    
    function dragRect() {
        var e = d3.event;
        for(var i = 0; i < self.rectData.length; i++){
            self.rectangleElement
                .attr('x', self.rectData[i].x += e.dx )
                .attr('y', self.rectData[i].y += e.dy );
        }
        self.rectangleElement.style('cursor', 'move');
        updateRect();
    }
    
    var dragC1 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint1);
    var dragC2 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint2);
    var dragC3 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint3);
    var dragC4 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint4);
    
    function dragPoint1() {
        var e = d3.event;
        self.pointElement1
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x += e.dx })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y += e.dy });        
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
    function dragPoint2() {
        var e = d3.event;
        self.pointElement2
            .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x += e.dx )
            .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y += e.dy );
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
    function dragPoint3() {
        var e = d3.event;
        self.pointElement3
            .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x += e.dx )
            .attr('cy', self.rectData[0].y += e.dy );     
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
    function dragPoint4() {
        var e = d3.event;
        self.pointElement4
            .attr('cx', self.rectData[0].x += e.dx )
            .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y += e.dy );
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
}//end Rectangle
```

```css
svg {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

rect {
    fill: lightblue;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button id='rectangle'>Rectangle</button>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of D3 v4 a selection no longer is an array of arrays but an object. The [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection) has it:

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection; they are now plain objects, improving performance.

When doing `self.rectangleElement[0][0]` in v3 you were accessing the first node in a selection. To get this node in v4 you need to call [`selection.node()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_node) on `self.rectangleElement`. With this your code becomes:

```
rect = d3.select(self.rectangleElement.node());
```

Have a look at the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qm6A/14/) for a working version.

Comment: That version is working OK because that fiddle is still using d3.js v3. I've updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/pjmdbq4s/ using d3.js v4 instead, but it's not working, console says [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null] on d3.v4.min.js:4

Comment: On the non-minified version - d3.v4.js, the same error shows but is on line #7383 [this.ownerDocument = parent.ownerDocument;]