# Migrating from D3.js v3 to D3.js v7 not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is similar to an earlier one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056927/migrating-from-d3-js-v3-to-d3-js-v4-not-working-a-select-issue). The difference is that  I am trying to migrate from v3 to v7. When I try to finish drawing the rectangle by clicking the mouse, it does not work. The only way I have to exit is by right clicking.

The code conversion what I have done is here.

```
d3.select('#rectangle').on('click', (event) =>{ new Rectangle(); });

var w = 600, h = 500;
var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
       // .attr({width: w, height: h});



function Rectangle() {
    var self = this;
    var rect, rectData = [];
    var isDown = false;
    var m1, m2, m3; 
    var isDrag = false;
    var deltaX, deltaY;

    svg.on('mousedown', (event) =>{
        m1 = d3.pointer(event);
        if (!isDown && !isDrag) {
            self.rectData = [ { x: m1[0], y: m1[1] }, { x: m1[0], y: m1[1] } ];
            self.rectangleElement = d3.select('svg').append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle').call(dragR);
          /*  self.pointElement1 = d3.select('svg').append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC1);
            self.pointElement2 = d3.select('svg').append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC2);            
            self.pointElement3 = svg.append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC3);
            self.pointElement4 = svg.append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC4);
*/
            updateRect();
            isDrag = false;
        } else { 
            isDrag = true;
        }
        isDown = !isDown;     
    })
    
    .on('mousemove', (event) =>{
        m2 = d3.pointer(event);
        if(isDown && !isDrag) { 
            self.rectData[1] = { x: m2[0], y: m2[1] };
            updateRect();
        } 
    });  
    
    function updateRect() {  
       rect = d3.select(self.rectangleElement.nodes()[0]);
    
        var x1 = (self.rectData[1].x - self.rectData[0].x > 0 ? self.rectData[0].x :  self.rectData[1].x);
        rect.attr("x", x1)
        .attr("y",  self.rectData[1].y - self.rectData[0].y > 0 ? self.rectData[0].y :  self.rectData[1].y)
        .attr("width", Math.abs(self.rectData[1].x - self.rectData[0].x))
        .attr("height", Math.abs(self.rectData[1].y - self.rectData[0].y));
          
/*
        var point1 = d3.select(self.pointElement1.nodes()[0]);

    point1.attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", self.rectData[0].x)
    .attr("cy", self.rectData[0].y);

    var point2 = d3.select(self.pointElement2.nodes()[0]);
    point2.attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx",  self.rectData[1].x)
    .attr("cy",  self.rectData[1].y);

    var point3 = d3.select(self.pointElement3.nodes()[0]);
    point3.attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx",  self.rectData[1].x)
    .attr("cy",  self.rectData[0].y);

    var point4 = d3.select(self.pointElement4.nodes()[0]);
    point4.attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx",  self.rectData[0].x)
    .attr("cy",  self.rectData[1].y);
*/
    }
       
       

    var dragR = d3.drag().on('drag', dragRect);

    function dragRect() {
        m3 = d3.pointer(event);
       for(var i = 0; i < self.rectData.length; i++){

           var rect= d3.select(self.rectangleElement.nodes()[0]);
           
         
           rect.attr('x', self.rectData[i].x += m3[0] )
                .attr('y', self.rectData[i].y += m3[1] );
          
       }
       rect.style('cursor', 'move');
       updateRect();
   }

   /* 

    var dragC1 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint1);
    var dragC2 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint2);
    var dragC3 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint3);
    var dragC4 = d3.drag().on('drag', dragPoint4);


    function dragPoint1() {

        m3 = d3.pointer(event);
        var point1 = d3.select(self.pointElement1.nodes()[0]);

        deltaX = m3[0] - parseFloat(point1.attr("cx"));
        deltaY = m3[1] - parseFloat(point1.attr("cy"));

        point1.attr("cx", function(d) { return( parseFloat(point1.attr("cx")) + m3[0])})
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return( parseFloat(point1.attr("cy")) + m3[1])});
       
        updateRect();   
    }  

    function dragPoint2() {

        m3 = d3.pointer(event);
        var point2 = d3.select(self.pointElement2.nodes()[0]);
      
        deltaX = m3[0] - self.rectData[1].x;
        deltaY = m3[1] - self.rectData[1].y;

        point2.attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x + deltaX  )
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y + deltaY  );

        updateRect();   
    }  

  function dragPoint3() {

        m3 = d3.pointer(event);
        var point3 = d3.select(self.pointElement3.nodes()[0]);

        deltaX = m3[0] - self.rectData[1].x;
        deltaY = m3[1] - self.rectData[0].y;
      
        point3.attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x + deltaX )
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[0].y + deltaY );

        updateRect();   
    }  

 function dragPoint4() {

        m3 = d3.pointer(event);
        var point4 = d3.select(self.pointElement4.nodes()[0]);
    
        deltaX = m3[0] - self.rectData[0].x;
        deltaY = m3[1] - self.rectData[1].y;
                              
        point4.attr('cx', self.rectData[0].x + deltaX )
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y + deltaY );

        updateRect();   
    }
*/

}
```

I have commented out a portion of the code related to resizing and dragging.

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: Please add a working copy of the code in d3 v3. This will make it more likely, that your question will be answered.

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/SunboX/vj4jtdg8/

Comment: I checked out your code with d3.js v4 and there it is already not working. So far I can see issues in the console with the svg selection, the d3.behavior and a callback. The errors thrown in the console should be enough guidance to figure it out. Maybe try first migrating to d3.js v4 and then move on to the next version. This should also make it simpler in case there are multiple breaking changes from the versions accumulating.