# D3 js V4 - Scatterplot configuration

Tags: d3.js

Someone knows why the circles are not shown in the graph?

```
var winPercentageByMonth = [
     {"month":1, "winPercentage":20},
     {"month":2, "winPercentage":90},
     {"month":3, "winPercentage":20},
     {"month":4, "winPercentage":51},
     {"month":5, "winPercentage":15},
     {"month":6, "winPercentage":22},
     {"month":7, "winPercentage":9},
     {"month":8, "winPercentage":6},
     {"month":9, "winPercentage":23},
     {"month":10, "winPercentage":7},
     {"month":11, "winPercentage": 40},
     {"month":12, "winPercentage": 45},
     {"month":13, "winPercentage":20},
     {"month":14, "winPercentage":14},
     {"month":15, "winPercentage":3},
     {"month":16, "winPercentage":21},
     {"month":17, "winPercentage":15},
     {"month":18, "winPercentage":69},
     {"month":19, "winPercentage":9},
     {"month":20, "winPercentage":6},
     {"month":20, "winPercentage":110},
     {"month":21, "winPercentage":7},
     {"month":22, "winPercentage": 40},
     {"month":23, "winPercentage": 45},
     {"month":24, "winPercentage": 45}

];


    var hs= 350;
    var ws = 400;



//create svg
var svgs = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attrs({
         width: ws, 
         height: hs
    });


//creeate placeholder circles
var circleMaker = svgs.selectAll("circle")
  .data(winPercentageByMonth)
  .enter()
    .append("circle");


//give circles attributes

var circleAttributes = circleMaker.attrs ({


      cx: function(d){
        return d.month*15;
      },

      cy: function(d){
        return h-(d.winPercentage);
      },

      r: function(d,i) {
        return Math.sqrt(i.winPercentage);
      },

      fill:function(d){
            if (d.winPercentage >10 & d.month > 5){
              return "#B82E00";
            }
            else{
              return "#B88A00";
            };
      }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to make sure that you are loading/requiring/importing the [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) script. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38209449/1446845) other answer for a detailed explanation.

Once that is done just check the errors in the console and it will giude you to solve your problems, i.e. tweak your attributes definitions as you have a few errors in there.

```
  cy: function(d){
    return hs-(d.winPercentage); // <= notice the `h` variable is now `hs`, h is undefined
  },

  r: function(d,i) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.winPercentage); // <= pass the data (`d`), not the index (`i`) 
  },
```

A working [bin](http://jsbin.com/xukotu/edit?html,js,output) with the above corrections.